# how to get revert at the previous timestamp of evm in testrpc

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc, nodejs, ethereumjs

I am testing my contracts so at some point i need to increase the timestamp of evm that i achieve through evm_timeIncrease but now i want to execute some functions on the basis of current timestamp but because of evm_increaseTime it get changed and continues from the new timestamp.

I try evm_revert , evm_snapshot but nothing get worked .
Please suggest any solution

testrpc v4+

node.js v8.4.0

truffle v3.4.3

Comment: I have the same question. I can see in the testrpc log that I saved a state, performed my action, then reverted the state, but the revert does not seem to have made any changes.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out @Satyam?

Comment: @blockchaindotsol No still waiting for answer